# Flex Action Script timeout issue

Tags: apache-flex

Our flex (flare) application keeps timing out when rendering large datasets. Is there anyway to prevent this? we have tried to increase the timeout in the Application tag and the compiler settings. Not mushc success.

Any other thoughts?

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may organize the rendering work in chunks and after processing each chunk, give back control to the system. There are many possible implementations, for instance start a timer that fires event each 500 ms and process a small chunk of the dataset in the event handler.

As a bonus, processing a large dataset in chunks will enable you to provide the user the option to cancel rendering easily.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing timeout is not advisable because on high network traffic it will bug users even more, the only solution is to do paging of long datasets, always load 50 to 100 items only at a time and let user navigate to pages by using pager controls.